# Find the general formula for the generating function $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^5} \frac{1}{1-x^{10}} \frac{1}{1-x^{25}} \frac{1}{1-x^{50}}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, math-software

Background:

I'd like to solve the Counting change problem by generating function.

The problem is described [here](https://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e2.xhtml#g_t1_002e2_002e2):

> How many different ways can we make change of $1.00, given half-dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies? More generally, can we write a procedure to compute the number of ways to change any given amount of money?

There are many possible ways, e.g. tree recursion, dynamic programming, SMT solver, etc.

My attempt is to use a generating function:

This problem can be modeled as counting the number of nonnegative integral solutions of the equation:

$\displaystyle{ e_1 + 5e_2 + 10e_3 + 25e_4 + 50e_5 = n}$

Thus the generating function is:

$\displaystyle{ g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^5} \frac{1}{1-x^{10}} \frac{1}{1-x^{25}} \frac{1}{1-x^{50}}}$

but how to find the general formula $h(n)$ for $g(x)$? i.e.

$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty h(n) x^n $

AFAIK, the traditional method is to use partial fractions, i.e.

$ \displaystyle{\frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^5} \frac{1}{1-x^{10}} \frac{1}{1-x^{25}} \frac{1}{1-x^{50}} = \frac{c_1}{1-x} + \frac{c_2}{1-x^5} + \frac{c_3}{1-x^{10}} + \frac{c_4}{1-x^{25}} + \frac{c_5}{1-x^{50}}}  $

then simplify it and solve $c_1$, $c_2$, $c_3$, $c_4$, $c_5$.

However, for this example it seems very difficult ... (or better method?)

My question is that

Is there any mathematical tool that can find the general formula of the  generating function directly? I have tried [the generating function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=expand+Divide%5B1%2C1-x%5D*Divide%5B1%2C1-Power%5Bx%2C5%5D%5D*Divide%5B1%2C1-Power%5Bx%2C10%5D%5D*Divide%5B1%2C1-Power%5Bx%2C25%5D%5D*Divide%5B1%2C1-Power%5Bx%2C50%5D%5D+to+order+100) in wolfrmalpha, it cannot get the general formula (although it can get Taylor series).

Thanks.

P.s. I believe that once we get the general formula, computing the number of ways to change any given amount of money will be very fast.

Comment: I don't see how such an (analytical) formula could exist.

Comment: Your partial fractions setup is missing some terms and is otherwise off. For example $1/(1-x^{10})=[1/(1-x^5)][1/(1+x^5)]$ which increases the power on $1/(1-x^5)$ to $2$ and introduces a term for $1/(1+x^5).$ There is more factoring to do...

Comment: @coffeemath You are right. I forget to factorization. Thanks! Sorry I'm not familiar with the partial fractions method. Do you think the following partial fractions setup correct? $ \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{1-x^5} \frac{1}{1-x^{10}} \frac{1}{1-x^{25}} \frac{1}{1-x^{50}} = \frac{1}{1-x} \frac{1}{(1-x^5)^2} \frac{1}{1+x^{5}} \frac{1}{(1-x^{25})^2} \frac{1}{1+x^{25}}  = \frac{c_1}{1-x} + \frac{c_2}{1-x^5} + \frac{c_3}{(1-x^5)^2} + \frac{c_4}{1+x^{5}} + \frac{c_5}{1-x^{25}} + \frac{c_6}{(1-x^{25})^2} + \frac{c_7}{1+x^{25}}$

Comment: @coffeemath Do you think the $ \frac{1}{1-x^{25}}$ need to further be factorized? (It can be [factorized](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=1-Power%5Bx%2C25%5D)), but the result will be not $\frac {c} {(1-rx)^t}$.

Comment: You must factorize over complex numbers and there are many multiple roots.

Comment: @chansey I think for partial fractions to be guaranteed to work one needs all terms in factorized denominator to be powers of linear or quadratic factors. Though I once did one with a quadratic factor which could have factored but used a linear for its numerator. Also all other denominator factors were coprime to it. [There may be some exceptions which ha0en to work but I don't know what these are.]

Comment: @BobDobbs One may avoid factoring irreducibe quadratic factors via using linear numerators. This is the way some calc texts do it

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Expand+%281-x%29%281-x%5E5%29%281-x%5E10%29%281-x%5E25%29%281-x%5E50%29

Comment: @BobDobbs Your wolfram link just expands the thing. That's not relevant to the setup for partial fractions.

Comment: @coffeemath the recursive equation of these numbers is not like fibonacci numbers...

Comment: There is a solution in *Concrete Mathematics*, Second Edition, by Graham, Knuth and Patashnik.  Several tricks are involved.  See Example 4, "A closed form for change", in section 7.3, starting on page 344.

Comment: Mathologer gives a complete solution for the special case where the total amount is a multiple of $100$ cents (which includes one dollar, of course), in a YouTube video: [Explaining the bizarre pattern in making change for a google dollars (infinite generating functions)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLbePGBOVeg)

Comment: @awkward Great video, thanks!

Comment: Also, in Knuth's Concrete Mathematics, he also introduced a trick to obtain the general formula.

Answer (score 1):

The partial fraction decomposition can be done theoretically but I wouldn't want to do it. As people have said in the comments, the problem is that there are many multiple roots so it's fairly annoying even to write down the general form let alone to solve for its coefficients, and your general form is not correct. Over $\mathbb{Q}$ the denominator factors as

$$(1 - x)^5 (1 + x)^2 \Phi_5(x)^4 \Phi_{10}(x)^2 \Phi_{25}(x)^2 \Phi_{50}(x)$$

where $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial); this follows from the factorization $x^n - 1 = \prod_{d \mid n} \Phi_d(x)$ and it means the general form of the partial fraction decomposition over $\mathbb{Q}$ is

$$\frac{c_1(x)}{(1 - x)^5} + \frac{c_2(x)}{(1 + x)^2} + \frac{c_5(x)}{\Phi_5(x)^4} + \frac{c_{10}(x)}{\Phi_{10}(x)^2} + \frac{c_{25}(x)}{\Phi_{25}(x)^2} + \frac{c_{50}(x)}{\Phi_{50}(x)}$$

where the $c_i$ are all polynomials of degree less than the degree of the denominator. Over $\mathbb{C}$ we'd have a summand for each of the $50^{th}$ roots of unity, many of which have multiplicities, but there's a lot of redundancy in this description because of Galois invariance so I think it's easier to think about the partial fraction decomposition over $\mathbb{Q}$.

If you want to compute the partial fraction decomposition from here you can do it by clearing denominators and then substituting in various roots of unity, although the multiplicities mean you may have to compute various derivatives also which could get messy. It's all theoretically a finite computation though.

It's also worth noting that the largest contributors to the sum will come from the $\frac{1}{(1 - x)^5}$ term (which will contribute a quartic polynomial) and the $\frac{1}{\Phi_5(x)^4}$ term (which will contribute a cubic [quasipolynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial) with period $5$). The terms with multiplicity $2$ in the denominator only contribute linear quasipolynomials and the final $\Phi_{50}(x)$ term only contributes a constant quasipolynomial (which is to say a periodic function, with period $50$). So if you only want an accurate *approximation* to the answer the generating function may be able to do that for you more easily than computing the whole thing.

Also it may be possible to simplify the computation by writing the generating function as $\frac{1}{(1 - x) Q(x^5)}$ where $Q(x) = (1 - x)(1 - x^2)(1 - x^5)(1 - x^{10})$ and first computing the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{Q(x)}$, then substituting in $x^5$ and multiplying by $\frac{1}{1 - x}$.

Comment: A lot of information. I need some time to digest (e.g. the computation of contributors and [quasipolynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-polynomial)), but I still learned a lot from you answer (e.g. [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)) . The last suggestion is very similar to [Mathologer's method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLbePGBOVeg) in the youtube video and Concrete Mathmatics as @awkward mentioned. Thanks!